# GetDate() causes error when used with EXEC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

MS SQL Server 2008.

Why does this parse ok:

```
CREATE TABLE #Held
(
    Value decimal(18,4)
)
INSERT #Held EXEC dbo.sp_Held '2013-06-27', NULL
```

But this gives a syntax error(*Incorrect syntax near 'day'.*):

```
CREATE TABLE #Held
(
    Value decimal(18,4)
)
INSERT #Held EXEC dbo.sp_Held DATEADD(day, -1, getdate()), NULL
```

?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass a literal value, or a variable, and nothing else to an [`EXEC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) - notably, you cannot have any form of complex expression or function invocation<sup>1</sup>. So if you want to compute a value, you need to place that in a variable in a separate statement:

```
CREATE TABLE #Held
(
    Value decimal(18,4)
)
DECLARE @a datetime
SET @a = DATEADD(day, -1, getdate())
INSERT #Held EXEC dbo.sp_Held @a, NULL
```

Also, you should avoid naming stored procedures starting with [`sp_`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx):

> Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures. Using the prefix can cause application code to break if there is a system procedure with the same name.

---

<sup>1</sup> Martin points out that *some* functions can be invoked, but it's very much the exception rather than the rule, so whilst my statement isn't 100% accurate, treating it as so will not harm you.

Comment: Some function invocations are OK. `@@IDENTITY` works inline. But `SCOPE_IDENTITY` doesn't. Presumably a hangover from when the `@@` ones were called global variables.